# Uploading photo albums without posting to users' News Feed

Tags: facebook-opengraph, photos, feed

Is there any way to create photo albums without disseminating them on users' News Feeds? [asking since +3 of our global clients are interested in simply storing old campaign assets off the record]

*Hugh Durkin from Facebook team told me to post this question here when I asked on PMD Community group

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're uploading and to where (you haven't specified in your question) adding the `no_feed_story` or `no_story` parameter should suppress the news feed story from the upload - (set to '1' or 'true')

I think the former is for OG actions and page milestones and the latter for uploads to photo albums, but i'm not 100% sure if they're also interchangeable